# Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) 9.4 Marketplace missing, how to install Plugin now?

Tags: plugins, bigdata, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've just installed **Pentaho Data Integration (PDI)** version 9.4 (Community Edtition). I'm following this [guide](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.0/Setup/Install_the_PDI_tools_and_plugins) to install the new Plugin. The problem is I don't have "**Marketplace**" in "T**ools -> Marketplace**" like the guide said (the Show plugin information isn't the thing I need).
[image: Tools->?]

I read on the internet that I can download the Zip file, extract and put it in the Plugin folder. But it doesn't work too (maybe because of the wrong structure). For example, if I want to install this [Big-data-plugin](https://github.com/pentaho/big-data-plugin) from Git Hub, I don't know what to do. My final goal is to have some Plugins to connect **Pentaho** with **HDFS**, and **Hbase**,...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In PDI 9.4 (CE), you can install the big data plugin and marketplace by copying and pasting files from "pdi-ce-<version>-<build>-hadoop-addon.zip" to your PDI's data-integration folder. You can follow the steps to install from [here](https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/pdf/implementation-guide/three-steps-to-install-pentaho-data-integration-ce.pdf)

Comment: I tried doing it and marketplace is still missing

Answer (score 0):

Turn out you have to download a full version of PDI on this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho-9.3/client-tools/pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428.zip/download) (1gb zip file)
I accidentally downloaded a separated version which doesn't have big-data-plugin available. After downloading the full version everything is already there, marketplace and big-data-plugin

Comment: The link points to  PDI 9.3, not 9.4